# MySQL Enum's always contain '' (empty string) in possibilities

Tags: mysql, enums

I'm trying to create a simple 'yes'/'maybe'/'no' Enum in MySQL with PhpMyAdmin
I set NULL to No, and 'maybe' as the default value

I am expecting an error when executing something like "SET EnumCol=''", because '' (an empty string) should not be a valid value.
But the query gets executed and the value gets set to '' - which means I'm forced to double check for this unwanted and illegal value whenever I read from the database!

Is this a bug in MySQL or PhpMyAdmin?
Does anyone know a way of disabling this behavior?

Thanks.

Answer (score 36):

Empty string is error indicator of invalid values in `ENUM`. From mysql [`ENUM` type manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html):

> *If you insert an invalid value into an ENUM (that is, a string not present in the list of allowed values), the empty string is inserted instead as a special error value.* This string can be distinguished from a “normal” empty string by the fact that this string has the numerical value 0. More about this later.

To disable this behaviour:

> *If strict SQL mode is enabled, attempts to insert invalid ENUM values result in an error.*

To enable strict mode see [Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

Answer (score -3):

ENUM's are a pain in the butt. unless you also need to set the value by a number, i would stay away from them.

instead, use a varchar column with a foreign key to a lookup table to restrict the values. that will make it impossible to insert a bad value.

Comment: But `ENUM` type manipulations will be faster then foreign key check.

Comment: true. but who cares? this is probably not an application that has 10k inserts per minute where switching to enum will improve performance. choosing enum over foreign keys for speed is a case of premature optimization.

Comment: I appreciate this alternative solution of using a lookup table with FK. It seems more extensible as well.